# Not allowed to load local resource from chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, xampp, localhost

I have developed a small website with a home page and a form for a project and when I open it in xaamp with the localhost command in chrome I have an issue with loading the local files and more specific the images

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please read [ask] and then [edit] your question and include a [mre]